# How to send Bulk data into Marketing Cloud through an API

Tags: rest, bulk, salesforce-marketing-cloud

How to send Bulk data into Marketing Cloud through an API

I want to know the process of sending bulk data into SFMC through API integration. There is a way to do it for few records but when it comes to large volume of data. What is the way to do it?

Comment: SFMC APIs are not meant for bulk data operations, IMO.

Comment: Is it not possible to send bulk data into SFMC through an API call?